# Golang send and receive udp packets simultaneously

Tags: go, udp, packets

I have a little problem. I want to receive and write udp packets with a DialUDP function. The problem is that it only can write and not receive udp packets (i think). How can i send a packet and let the program wait on a respond from the server?

my code:

```
if programPacketType == "udp"{
    server,err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", programAddressInput)
    checkError(err)
    lServer, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", programLocalAddressInput)
    checkError(err)


    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", server, lServer)
    checkError(err)

    i := 0
    for {
        msg := strconv.Itoa(i)
        i++
        buf := []byte(msg)
        _,err := conn.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(msg, err)
        }
        fmt.Println("sended:", i, "to connected server")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
```

thanks.

(Pls ignore grammatical mistakes,)

Comment: Why do you think you cannot receive packets? (this code doesn't attempt to receive at all)

Comment: This code doesnt receive indeed. But thats not the problem, please read my question again.

Comment: Sorry, I have read it again, and still don't understand. If you want to send a packet then wait for a reply, you need to read from the connection after sending the packet (or concurrently), which you haven't done. Have you tried using `conn.Read`, and if so, what did you try and what didn't work?